# What are the different values of $\int_0^1 {dz \over 1+z^2} $ when all possible paths of integration are considered?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, computational-mathematics

What are the different values of $$\int_0^1 {dz \over 1+z^2} $$ when all possible paths of integration are considered?

---

I only know how to integrate.

Comment: How is it defined when you have a path that passes through $\pm i$?

Comment: @Dr.MV: Just polishing off a drop of wine before retiring :-). Hope you are well. Complex analysis is not my strongest point :-(.

Comment: Hope you're well also.  Stay thirsty my friend.  And no I am not close to the world's most interesting man.  ;-)

Comment: Provided the contour does not enclose either of the poles, the contour integral is independent of the path. Therefore, if the path does not enclose either one of the poles, then the answer is $\pi/4$.  If the contour encircles a pole, we pick up an additional $\pm \pi$, depending on the orientation of the contour.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Good night Sir!

Comment: Good night.  - Mark

Comment: Thank you! The answer is pie/4.

Comment: In the complex plane you can go around the pole at $i$ any number of times clockwise or counterclockwise.  Same for the pole at $-i$. We must be prepared for a potentially different value for any number of revolutions in either direction around both poles. We ultimately get an infinite set!